# Stop the Player (JLayer) inside a java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, media-player

I have a thread to play an audio but when i close the form i want to stop the player playing the audio file my thread run method is:

```
public static Player playplayer;
public static FileInputStream fis;
public static BufferedInputStream bis;
public void run(){
   while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
       try{
          String file="E://Net Beans Work Space//The Imran's Regression"
            + "//src//imranregression//audio//iron man.mp3";
          fis= new FileInputStream(file);
          bis= new BufferedInputStream(fis);
          playplayer = new Player(bis);           
          playplayer.play();            
       }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.print("ERROR "+e);
       }
   }
```

My way of stop my player what i'm doing is:

```
  private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
  try{
      BGMusic.fis.close();
      BGMusic.bis.close();
      BGMusic.playplayer.close();      //want to close my player here
      audioplay.interrupt();   //stopping my thread here

  }catch(Exception e){

      return;
  }
}
```

The thing is that it was not doing as i want to do to stop my thread as well as to stop playing the audio. How can i achieve this? Please help me Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this also an Android related question?  BTW - Why did you delete your earlier question?

Comment: First of all it is not an android related question secondally the last question was being ignored the thing is i just want any hint about my things i have done wrong so as to sure that i am doing in wrong way plus i have tried a bit more with my code so again this time unseccesful

Comment: *"the last question was being ignored"* 1) That is not a valid reason for deleting it 2) Starting a new question that is exactly the same is pointless. 3) Given I spent time tidying that first one up, I am quite annoyed.  4) That last one might not seem important to you, but since I am one of the few people who look at such questions, I feel you are hurting your chances of getting an answer - ***at all.***

Comment: Sorry Andrew Sir Please give me a chance it will not happen again Please

Comment: You must use a Boolean typo variable in order to check in while()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this as:

```
 Thread audioplay=null;
```

start the thread normally!
then!

```
    if (audioplay != null) {
        bg.Terminate();
        playplayer.close();
    try {
        audioplay.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        //catch the exception
    }
        System.out.print("The thread has stopped");
    }
```

your Thread class should have these:
i.e you should use a volatile Boolean variable to check in while()!

```
    private volatile boolean running = true;

public void Terminate() {
    running = false;
}

public void run(){
   while(running){
       try{
    String file="E://Net Beans Work Space//The Imran's Regression"
            + "//src//imranregression//audio//iron man.mp3";
         fis= new FileInputStream(file);
         bis= new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        playplayer = new Player(bis);



            playplayer.play();


}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("ERROR "+e);
}

   }
```

That is! you're completely done thatch it  !

Comment: Yes i forget to add the Boolean variable let me check it for working! wait

Comment: yes it works fine for me the thing is that i was not doing the right code thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Moving these three lines

```
 BGMusic.fis.close();
 BGMusic.bis.close();
 BGMusic.playplayer.close();      //want to close my player here
```

right after the while closes

```
 while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    //stuff
 }
```

should work. For my part I'd prefer to create a boolean value to check if the thread should exit and use `join()` to wait for the thread to finish.